# How to use a LoaderManager and a CursorLoader inside an OnClickItemListener of an Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-cursorloader

I have a simple (?) Android application that begins with an Activity ("First Activity") with a ListView that lists three items: Beginning, Intermediate and Advanced. So far, so good. What I want to happen next is if the user clicks on e.g. Beginning, a SQLite database will be queried and all items designated "Beginning" in the database will be retrieved. I then want a second Activity ("Second Activity") to launch and have all the items from the query displayed in a ListView on that Activity. I have this working using a cursor, but I'm trying to update my code to use a LoaderManager and a CursorLoader. I think that I need to put an onCreateLoader method inside the ListView's onItemClick method in the First Activity. To give an example, I'm thinking of code like this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView listview = getListView();
    String[] values = new String[] {
            "Beginning", "Intermediate", "Advanced"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, <myUri>,
            <myFields>, <myQuery>, null, null); 
}               
        }

    });
}
```

}

Also in my onClickItem, I'm going to create an Intent and stuff it with a Bundle of data (my Second Activity's ListView will need this data for its onItemClick method). Anyway, when I try this, Eclipse is unhappy with the onCreateLoader inside the onItemClick, giving me lots of error messages about mismatched curly braces, missing semi-colons, etc. So what am I doing wrong? How do I query my database when a listitem is clicked? If I move the onCreateLoader method outside of the onItemClick method, but within the setItemClickListener, I don't get error messages, but then how do I reference it within my onItemClick method?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Many thanks in advance!

---

Thanks very much for both answers! I'm an Android newbie; I'm trying to implement your suggestions and am stuck once again. I created a new Activity called GetLevelData. My first activity now looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView listview = getListView();
    final String[] values = new String[] {
            "Beginning", "Intermediate", "Advanced"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent choice = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.MyProject.project.GetLevelData.class);
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            String chosenValue = values[position];
            dataBundle.putString("Level",chosenValue);
            choice.putExtras(dataBundle);
            try {
                startActivity(choice);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                d.setTitle("MyProjectActivity line 60");
                TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setText(e.toString());
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {

            }
        }

    });
}
```

My new Activity looks like this:

```
public class GetLevelData extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.leveldata);

    Intent myData = getIntent();
    Bundle info = myData.getExtras();

    if (info != null){
        TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String level = info.getString("Level");
        myTextView.setText(level);
    }
}
```

}

textView1 is a TextView inside a LinearLayout in leveldata.xml in my layout folder. When I try to run this, at startActivity, I get an exception: Activity not found. What am I missing?  I'

Comment: In the onClick I would start a new Activity, this does all the loading then either displays the result or passes onto a 3rd activity (like you want to do) to display the result. That way you can get some clarity in your code and each Activity has just one responsibility. It may make it clearer how to use a Loader for you then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it simpler pass the choice to the second activity, not the cursor. Also `CursorLoader` is for content handlers not for general cursors. Last time I did something like this I believe I inherited [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

Thus, pass the choice in an extra in the intent, and let the second activity do the query.

Comment: Thanks very much, Tobias. Do you know of a link that has a good, simple example of how to use AsyncTaskLoader?

Comment: Yes, Tobias - I tried to ask my question in a comment, but it wouldn't take - maybe because I was including code? Anyway, I'll ask questions in new threads from now on. Your suggestion to add my activity to the manifest was the problem. I'm an Android noob and I keep getting pulled away from this project, so I feel like I have to learn Java for Android over and over again. Erk. And I did mark your answer as helpful, but I don't know if that took either. So thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the very last question for anyone finding this post:

`textView1 is a TextView inside a LinearLayout in leveldata.xml in my layout folder. When I try to run this, at startActivity, I get an exception: Activity not found. What am I missing?`

You need to register the new activity in the manifest. Using something like this in the AndroidManifest file:

```
<activity android:name="com.my.package.GetLevelData"
        android:label="Level Data" />
```